# How can I track which page I am on in asp.net-mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a link in a master page that says "Send feedback" which brings up a new web page.

When I go to that new page, I have a form and I want to populate a textbox with the URL that the person was on when they clicked the "Send Feedback" button.

How can I grab the current URL to pass that over? Should I do this on the client side (jQuery) or on the asp.net-mvc server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass along the URL as you can check the `UrlReferrer` property on the `Request` object in the "Send feedback" action.

Use this as your controller action:

```
public ActionResult SendFeedback(string message) {
   var referrer = Request.UrlReferrer;
   feedbackService.Send(message, referrer);
}
```

Comment: Be careful using this because it can end in a null reference exception if the user has disabled the http referrer header. I would recommend using the solution provided by @Darin Dimitrov.

Comment: It wouldn't throw an `NullReferenceException` if you just read it and it be null. It would if you perform an operation on it, however. But I also think Darin's method is better. Or maybe just a hidden field in the form with `Request.Url.RawUrl` as value. That would be my preference I think.

Answer (score 7):

You could pass `Request.Url.RawUrl` as query string parameter to the `Send feedback` action which could itself store it as a hidden field in the form which will be reposted back and allowing to redirect back to the original page once the feedback is submitted. Example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Send feedback", 
    "Index", 
    "Feedback", 
    new { returnUrl = Request.Url.RawUrl }
)
```

Comment: This would be the preferred method. `Request.UrlReferrer` can produce a null reference if the user has disabled the referrer header.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it Server Side(preferred) using

> [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)

For implementing it client side, use a hidden variable and then use a form post.

something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="referredPage" name="referredPage"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(){
            $("#referredPage").val(window.location.href);
        });
    })
<script>
```

Comment: wouldnt that give me the SendFeedback page itself (not the previous page ??)

Comment: @ooo: You can store the Request.UrlReferrer as either a session variable or render it as a hidden variable in the Send FeedBack page so that it can retrieved back.